# how to restore formatting to libreoffice writer comments

Tags: libreoffice

In the attached image you can see that the lines connecting the comments to the edited text have become white on white. Also the commenters were all color coded before, but now all white on back background.

I probably caused this change by trying to make the background for the Styles column the same as the paper instead of charcoal gray. Why on earth would it be designed that way? I can fix the Styles by toggling off 'show previews' however I just can't find where to change the formatting of the comments and associated lines.

Does anyone else know?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles on this after having the same problem. In my case, after a little frustration and failure to find any setting to help, I found that the only way to fix the problem was to change the OS desktop theme.

I'm using ubuntu 21.04 and it had a dark theme which was probably OK most of the time but some applications haven't really sorted out the coding to use the right colours in the right place. I had to `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` then run it and change the theme to something more traditional.